# Python Imap [WinError 10060] - Server issue

Tags: python, server, port, imap, gmail-imap

I am attempting to establish a connection to Gmail though the Python imaplib library and have run into some issues. I have written the following code based off of the library:

```
*import imaplib
user = ''
pw = Path('C:/Users/9volpa7/Documents/Reporting/Ad-hoc/gmail_pw.txt').read_text()
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(host = 'imap.gmail.com',port=49152)
mail.login(user, pw)*
```

Which has consistently returned me a **TimeoutError: [WinError 10060].** I have tried adjusting the referenced port to ones that I know are established and listening and yet the connection still does not happen in sufficient time. I do not have the option to pass through a *timeout* argument which is available in similar libraries but also does not work for me.

Could this be something wrong with the host server?

Comment: Where did you get port 49152?  The IMAP server port is 993.

Comment: I had actually tried using port 993 to no avail. After that I had tried a myriad of things one of which was changing the ports to live ones on my local. Was more of a shot in the dark

Comment: Well, 993 is absolutely the port you have to use.  Check your computers firewall or your networks firewall.  Many companies for example will block it by default.

Comment: Oh that's a good idea! What exactly would I be looking to grant access to? The Secure Socket Tunneling Protocal?

Comment: "Secure IMAP" or "Port 993".